# Should I worry about permissions on USB drives?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, usb-storage

I'm formatting USBs for use mostly with Ubuntu, but I want to make sure there won't be issues with permissions or access on other common computer platforms.

How should I format these USB drives so that they can be read and written on Windows, MacOS, and Linux flavor systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT32 file format has no file permissions and can be read by most OSes.  To avoid issues as described in the original question, use FAT32.  Beware, you might hit FAT32's limits for file sizes and maximum disk sizes.  My memory is 4GB maximum file size and 2 TB maximum disk size.

http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm

Comment: A better question might be "Why are you not using cloud storage for the current project?" Beware that USB flash disks are not permanent storage.

Comment: @sigma2sigma, exFAT doesn't have the size limits and has been adopted as the default format for large SD cards.  It's Windows proprietary, but MacOS handles it.  The fact that it's proprietary means that it may not be supported by default in Linux distros that are sticklers on open source, but there's a FUSE-based implementation for Linux that is always available, and likely included by default on a distro like Ubuntu.